# Non-continuous CorePlot line graph (like the graph of y = 1/x)

Tags: iphone, math, graph, line, core-plot

I am writing an iPhone app that uses CorePlot for graphing a line plot (Using `CPScatterPlot`).  I need to graph a line plot that is not continuous (like y=1/x or y=floor(x)).

How would I go about doing this?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using the data source method `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` to provide graph data, return `nil` from it to prevent lines from being drawn between the points adjacent to the current.  This can be used to create the desired affect by inserting an extra record where the gap is needed.